# System.Windows.Forms.dll COM Interop by regasm, missing a couple of classes

Tags: com, interop, regasm

i have used regasm from .NET interop tools to provide the System.Windows.Forms.dll classes as COM objects but there are a couple of classes missing, for example the class OpenFileDialog, although regasm registered it successfully.

Does anyone know why only a few classes are registered.
->
I want to use the OpenFileDialog class as COM object.

My Windows version is Windows 7 Pro 32bit with -Net Framework 4.0
Thanks!

Comment: That was a rather horrible mistake, these classes were already registered when you installed .NET.  Good odds you screwed up your registry beyond reasonable repair.  No, you are never going to get OpenFileDialog, it is not [ComVisible].  There's no point to it, other language runtimes have their own support for the standard Windows dialogs.